# Trouble downloading file from Gdrive : 403 forbidden error

Tags: google-drive-api

I have a website with google drive file picker feature, which lets user's select file from the Gdrive account and upload to my website.

This functionality was working fine but suddenly it stopped working from last 3-4 days and I am getting error "403 Forbidden : client do not have permission".
Can someone please advice what can be the issue ?

Comment: Hello @sagargdrive, are you refreshing your access token? Have you added any new scopes to the project? Cheers!

Comment: can you please  show the code that accesses google?

Comment: @ale13 : No the code is not refreshing the access token. I get reponse JSON from google drive api and from there I send downloadFile path to my backend to download the file. The backend code is implemented in C# which uses webclient get method to download file and this is the point it is failing to download and gives error.

Comment: Hello @sagargdrive, what results are you getting if you try [OAuth 2.0 Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/)?

Comment: Thanks @ale13 for quick reply.  I am using V2 of google drive api and I can not find V2 endpoint in OAuth 2.0 playground. The other thing is I do not have access to developer console of google drive so not really sure if this is related to configuration issue or google itself is restricting the download from backend server request?

Comment: @sagargdrive what about this: what results are you getting if you try [this](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/get)?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the issue you are encountering is mostly due to the fact that you're not using a **valid** access token for your operation.

The `403 Forbidden` client error response code indicates that the server understood the request but refuses to authorize it.

#### Solution

**Identify the access scopes**

In order to get the appropriate access token, you should compare the scopes included in the access token response to the scopes required to access the features and functionality of your application dependent upon the Drive API.

If you have recently changed your scopes for your application, you will need to get a **new access token** which will correspond to the new scopes you have used.

Declaring multiple scopes can be done like this:

```
string[] scopes = new string[] { DriveService.Scope.DriveAppsReadonly,
                                 DriveService.Scope.DriveAppdata,
                                 ...
};
```

**Refresh your access token**

According to the [Using OAuth 2.0 to Access Google APIs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2) documentation:

> Access tokens have limited lifetimes. If your application needs access to a Google API beyond the lifetime of a single access token, it can obtain a refresh token. A refresh token allows your application to obtain new access tokens.

So, in order to still be able to perform all the operations as you did before, you will need to refresh your access token.

**Reference**

- [Using OAuth 2.0 to Access Google APIs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2);
- [Drive v2](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/about-auth).

Comment: As per https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/application-development/upcoming-changes-to-the-google-drive-api-and-google-picker-api

"It’s important to note that Drive API calls to files.get or revisions.get that do not download media content (i.e. do not set the query parameter of ?alt=media) will not be affected."

Can this be causing the download file issue ? 
If I remove ?alt=media from downloadUrl I am able to download the file.

Comment: Hello @sagargdrive, `downloadUrl` is short lived and might stop working. As an alternative, you should use `webContentLink` instead. Cheers!

Comment: Hi @ale13 Thank you for your valuable suggestions. I will check on that. :)